# Combine content from 2 files Programming In C

Tags: c, loops

I would like to combine contents from 2 files. but i unable to do it.

My output seem like

```
Username: admin
Password: password123

Username: admin
Password: password456

Username: admin
Password: password789

Username: admin
Password: p@ssw0rd

Username: admin123
Password: password123
```

But i would like to do like this output

```
Username: admin
Password: password123

Username: admin
Password: password456

Username: admin
Password: password789

Username: admin
Password: p@ssw0rd

Username: admin123
Password: password123

Username: admin123
Password: password456

Username: admin123
Password: password789

Username: admin123
Password: p@ssw0rd
```

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fpUser, *fpPass;

    char user[100], pass[100];  
    fpUser = fopen("username.txt","r");
    fpPass = fopen("password.txt","r");

    if (fpUser==NULL || fpPass==NULL)
    {
             printf("Username or Password File Cannot Found\n");
             exit(0);
    } else {
        while(fgets(user , 100 , fpUser) != NULL)
        {   
            do
            {
                printf("Username: %s\n", user);
                printf("Password: %s\n", pass);
            }
            while (fgets(pass , 100 , fpPass) != NULL);     
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The inner loop shouldn't work at all, since you're printing `pass` before you read `pass` from the file. The inner loop needs to be a `while` loop, just like the outer loop. Then you need to `rewind` the file after the inner loop finishes.

Comment: what do you mean by `Combine content from 2 files ` ? Do you want to put one after the other or ....

Comment: It really depends on what your 2 files contain. How do you plan to validate your reads? by line? (e.g. line 1 file 1 goes with line 2 file 2?) Are extraneous blank lines possible?

Comment: @Garry it is an aside-comment, but storing passwords in files always comes back to bite one in the rear.  If you need a simple password database, take a hash of inputted password and store that in a file.  Then to challenge the user, ask for a password and convert it to a hash using the same values (and compare if the hashes are the same).  It's more difficult to figure out a password that will make the hashes equal. (This advice is not fool proof, but is far better than stored passwords).

Comment: actually i want to combine contents from multiple to multiple. for example: print out user A combine all password, user B combine all password and etc.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rethink your loop. I think you want something like this:

```
 while((fgets(user , 100 , fpUser) != NULL) &&
              (fgets(pass , 100 , fpPass) != NULL))
        {
            printf("Username: %s", user);
            printf("Password: %s\n", pass);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Given the files `username.txt`:

```
admin
admin
admin123
admin123
user1
user2
user3
```

and `password.txt`:

```
password
badmin
x_234$yz00o@
n@@dles
p1ckL3z
sandW1ch3z
```

with the new loop the program outputs:

```
Username: admin
Password: password

Username: admin
Password: badmin

Username: admin123
Password: x_234$yz00o@

Username: admin123
Password: n@@dles

Username: user1
Password: p1ckL3z

Username: user2
Password: sandW1ch3z
```

Notice that I have removed the newline from the first call to `printf()`, since `fgets()` reads through the newline and keeps it. Also notice that the program simply stops when it runs out of passwords or usernames.

## Update:

@David C. Rankin suggested that the code should handle blank lines in the input. This is a really good idea, that was vaguely in my mind before he mentioned it, but I was too lazy to really entertain the notion. Here is a modified version of the whole program that accomplishes this. I added two pointers to `char` in the declarations to receive the return values from the calls to `fgets()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fpUser, *fpPass;

    char *isUser, *isPass;
    char user[100], pass[100];
    fpUser = fopen("username.txt","r");
    fpPass = fopen("password.txt","r");

    if (fpUser==NULL || fpPass==NULL)
    {
        printf("Username or Password File Cannot Found\n");
        exit(0);
    } else do {
            while ((isUser = fgets(user, 100, fpUser)) != NULL &&
                   user[0] == '\n')
                continue;
            while ((isPass = fgets(pass, 100, fpPass)) != NULL &&
                   pass[0] == '\n')
                continue;
            if (isUser && isPass) {
                printf("Username: %s", user);
                printf("Password: %s\n", pass);
            }
        } while (isUser && isPass);
        
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the files `username.txt`:

```
admin
admin




admin123
admin123
user1
user2






user3
```

and `password.txt`:

```
password
badmin

x_234$yz00o@
n@@dles
p1ckL3z


sandW1ch3z
anotherpass
longforapass
```

You can't see it here, but the `password.txt` file started with a blank line. Here is the new output:

```
Username: admin
Password: password

Username: admin
Password: badmin

Username: admin123
Password: x_234$yz00o@

Username: admin123
Password: n@@dles

Username: user1
Password: p1ckL3z

Username: user2
Password: sandW1ch3z

Username: user3
Password: anotherpass
```

Comment: Maybe an `if (*user != '\n' && *pass != '\n') { /* then consider OK */ }`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin-- good point. See the update to my answer. I am not sure that my solution is the cleanest. Maybe you have another idea?

Comment: Yep, that's much better. You scanning forward over blank likes works as well. That's should do it for this Q.

Answer (score 0):

Postmaster, you can close this case. i have been found the answer which is using rewind() in inner looping.